# Всплывающее окно с куки

Tags: cookie, javascript

Задача простая - создать всплывающее окно которое будет показываться на сайте один раз за сессию, похимичив с кодом вот что получилось - смотрю через хром, там в куки попадает - но окно всплывает каждый раз,почему?

```
    var cookie_value = 0

function get_cookie(name){
var cookie_name = name + "="

if (document.cookie.length > 0){
start_index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name)

if (start_index != -1) {
start_index += cookie_name.length

end_index = document.cookie.indexOf(";", start_index)

if (end_index == -1){
end_index = document.cookie.length
}

cookie_value=unescape(document.cookie.substring(start_index, end_index))

}

}

if(cookie_value == 0){
document.cookie="pop_once = 1"
PopupMe()
}

}

function PopupMe(){
setTimeout('__PopupMe()',1000)
}

function __PopupMe(){
myleft=(screen.width)?(screen.width+500)/2:1;mytop=(screen.height)?(screen.height-200)/2:50;
settings='top=' + mytop + ',left=' + myleft +',width=250,height=150,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,fullscreen=no'
PopupWin=window.open('http://ampheek.com/popped.htm','PopupWin', settings);
PopupWin.focus();
setTimeout('PopupWin.close()',7000);}
```

Comment: Потому что у вас ошибка. По смыслу все правильно, а искать ошибку в таком желания не возникает

Comment: @donkey совсем плохой код?

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, в коде нигде не вызывается _get_cookie_, соответственно, значение _cookie_value_ не меняется и всегда `0`

Answer (score 2):

Видимо значение сравнивается с нулем (типа `(string)document.cookie == (boolean)0` *- false*), а не со строкой.

Я бы вот так сделал вообще:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

if(!getCookie('pop_once')){
    document.cookie = 'pop_once=true';
    PopupMe();
}
```

А еще таймауты:

```
setTimeout(__PopupMe,1000);
```

Comment: на самом деле просто нигде _getCookie_ не вызывался